# KKT conditions with equality max(|x1|,|x2|)

Tags: optimization, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm learning how to solve optimization problems with constraints, but im confused about applying the KKT conditions for the following problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(x_1, x_2)\\ \text{subject to} & \max \left( |x_1|,|x_2| \right) = 3\end{array}$$

I guess the Lagrangian will be

$$L = f(x_1,x_2) - \lambda (\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)-3)$$

I am not sure how to continue with taking the derivative w.r.t x1, x2, and $\lambda$.

I know that $\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)=3$ is a square with $ -3 \leq x_1 \leq 3$ and $ -3 \leq x_2 \leq 3$.

Comment: If the constraint is an equality, why use KKT?

Comment: Are you sure that $\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)=3$ is a square?

Comment: Yes, it is a square of lines so to say (only the boundaries count)

Comment: The $ -3 \leq x_1 \leq 3$ and $ -3 \leq x_2 \leq 3$ part suggests the interior matters, too. You can rewrite the constraint using the $\infty$-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve it in four parts (the $\pm$ gives two choices for both ways of $\{j, k\} = \{1,2\}$):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(x_1, x_2)\\ \text{subject to} & x_j = \pm 3 \\ & x_k \leq 3 \\ & -x_k \leq 3 \end{array}$$

In another words you consider each side of the square separately.
Actually, since you have the condition, for example in the first case, that $x_1=3$ and $-3 \leq x_2 \leq 3$, you might just want to plug $x_1=3$ into $f$ and get a single variable function to minimize on $[-3, 3]$.

Then pick the minimum of these four solutions.

Comment: I tried separating the four cases but i didn't know how to continue. I'm going to try your suggestion. Thanks a lot